# Shuffle groups of sublists in Python

Tags: python

I want to shuffle this list:

```
[[1, 'A'], [2, 'A'], [6, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'C'], [5, 'C'], [7, 'F']]
```

But I need groups identified by sublists second elements to stay together, so that the shuffled list could look like this:

```
[[6, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [7, 'F'], [1, 'A'], [2, 'A'], [4, 'C'], [5, 'C']]
```

Where all 'B', 'F', 'A', and 'C' sublists stay together.

I'm guessing using a combination of shuffle and groupby would do the trick, but I don't know where to start with this. Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
items = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'A'], [6, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'C'], [5, 'C'], [7, 'F']]

import itertools, operator, random

groups = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(items, operator.itemgetter(1))]
random.shuffle(groups)
shuffled = [item for group in groups for item in group]

print(shuffled)
```

Prints for example:

```
[[4, 'C'], [5, 'C'], [1, 'A'], [2, 'A'], [7, 'F'], [6, 'B'], [3, 'B']]
```

Comment: Impressive. Could you elaborate on the list comprehension for groups? More specifically, **list(g) for _, g**

Comment: `groupby` gives you (group key, group members) pairs. I don't need the key, so I use the `_` placeholder to show that. And I make a list of each group's members because otherwise it's a weird fragile *"itertools._grouper object"*.

Answer (score 5):

Giving each group a random number and sorting by that. Sublists stay together because Pythons sorting is stable.

---

Update years later: Using a `defaultdict` looks nicer and only generates one random number for each group, not one for every element:

```
from random import random
from collections import defaultdict

r = defaultdict(random)
items.sort(key=lambda item: r[item[1]])
```

As squeezed oneliner:

```
items.sort(key=lambda i, r=defaultdict(random): r[i[1]])
```

Back to original answer:

---

```
items = [[1, 'A'], [2, 'A'], [6, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'C'], [5, 'C'], [7, 'F']]

import random

r = {b: random.random() for a, b in items}
items.sort(key=lambda item: r[item[1]])

print(items)
```

Prints for example:

```
[[6, 'B'], [3, 'B'], [4, 'C'], [5, 'C'], [7, 'F'], [1, 'A'], [2, 'A']]
```

---

The two lines could be combined, then you don't have that extra variable flying around afterwards.

```
items.sort(key=lambda item, r={b: random.random() for a, b in items}: r[item[1]])
```

Comment: I think this is better than the accepted answer.  It has fewer lines and fewer imports.

Comment: @zondo It's also (on my PC) more than twice as fast for this example, and... I think it's way more interesting than the boring obvious groupby solution :-). But it could be slower if there are many items/groups.

Comment: @zondo I "saved" another line :-)

Comment: It's too bad you can't save another.

Comment: Well I could use `__import__('random').random()`, then I wouldn't need that extra `import random` line.

Comment: You could also remove the `r` variable and put it right into your `items.sort` line.

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, then it doesn't work.

Comment: I meant to do `items.sort(key = lambda item: {b: random.random() for a, b in items}[item[1]])`, but I hadn't actually looked closely at your edit, and I now see that yours with `r` being a default argument for the `lambda` is more efficient than mine.

Comment: That's what I thought, and it really doesn't work. For some reason it unexpectedly always crashes with KeyError, and if I use a copy of `items` instead, then as expected it rips the sublists apart.

Comment: I guess the reason for the KeyError is that `sort` has some elements temporarily not in the list when it asks for their keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict to group without needing to sort then just shuffle the values the flatten into a flat list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import shuffle
from itertools import chain


def shuffle_groups(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for v, k in l:
        d[k].append([k, v])
    vals = list(d.values())
    shuffle(vals)
    return chain(*vals)
```

Output:

```
In [9]: list(shuffle_groups(l))
Out[9]: [['A', 1], ['A', 2], ['F', 7], ['B', 6], ['B', 3], ['C', 4], ['C', 5]]

In [10]: list(shuffle_groups(l))
Out[10]: [['C', 4], ['C', 5], ['B', 6], ['B', 3], ['A', 1], ['A', 2], ['F', 7]]

In [11]: list(shuffle_groups(l))
Out[11]: [['F', 7], ['B', 6], ['B', 3], ['A', 1], ['A', 2], ['C', 4], ['C', 5]]
```

Some timings:

```
In [5]: l =[choice(l) for _ in range(100000)]

In [6]: timeit _groupy(l)
10 loops, best of 3: 139 ms per loop

In [7]: timeit shuffle_groups(l)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.1 ms per loop
```