# Python shuffle content of sublists of a list

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle, nested-lists

I have a list of lists in python: `l = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]` and I want to shuffle each sublist. How can I achieve this?

Note, that the order of the sublists should be preserved while their content is shuffled. This is different from previous questions, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35214352/4920424), where the order is shuffled and the content preserved.

I have tried the following:

```
import random

x = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]

random.shuffle(x) # This shuffles the order of the sublists,
                  # not the sublists themselves.

x = [ random.shuffle(sublist) for sublist in x ] # This returns None
                                                 # for each sublist.

print(x)
```

Comment: Duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214352/shuffle-groups-of-sublists-in-python]

Comment: @sujittiwari: That's not a duplicate of this question at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuffle groups of sublists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214352/shuffle-groups-of-sublists-in-python)

Comment: @UbdusSamad: This is the exact same question suggested by sujittiwari. And it's not a duplicate.

Comment: My Apologies, Seemed pretty much the same. @TimPietzcker

Comment: I added a note to explain the difference: [Shuffle groups of sublists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35214352/4920424) shuffles the sublists but preserves their content. I want to shuffle the content of the sublists, but preserve their order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the "x =" on the 4th line.

Code:

```
import random

x = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]

random.shuffle(x) # This shuffles the order of the sublists,
                  # not the sublists themselves.

[ random.shuffle(sublist) for sublist in x ] # This returns None
                                                 # for each sublist.

print(x)
```

Following suggestion in comment, here's a newer version:

```
import random
x = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
random.shuffle(x) 
for sublist in x:
    random.shuffle(sublist) 
print(x)
```

Comment: While this works, it's ugly to use a list comprehension only for its side effects. A proper `for` loop would be much better.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's a cool trickshot to solve a post by only deleting 2 characters though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`shuffle` works inplace and returns nothing, so use:

```
random.shuffle(x)
for i in x:
    random.shuffle(i)
print(x)
```

Comment: you can use ``shuffled(x)`` to return the list instead of shuffling inplace.

Comment: @allo: Where does `shuffled` come from? It's certainly not a Python built-in, and it's not part of the Python standard library.

Comment: Sorry shuffled is indeed not in the standard lib, but a part of a codebase here. I am so used to it because it is analog to ``sorted`` that I thought its python standard.

Answer (score -1):

You can try another function called sample like this. I use python 3.6.

from random import *
x=[sample(i, len(i)) for i in x]
shuffle(x)

it is very easy! Although it is easy to solve it, you can try another function.